# Apache Ignite NearCaches Vs CachMode

Tags: caching, ignite, gridgain, near-cache

Apache Ignite has two concepts, one  of them is `NearCache`, and another one is the `CacheMode` enumaration.

What is the main difference between two concepts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Near cache is the local hot cache that keeps often accessed data. It significantly speeds up data processing, saving time on network round-trips.

CacheMode defines how your data will be stored. It could be `LOCAL` for single node, which means data are not distributed in grid. Other two `PARTITIONED` and `REPLICATED` means respectively: cache data divided between nodes on some equal parts (called partitions) or each node keeps full data from that cache.

`PARTITIONED` allows you to keep in grid more data than available in separate machine, `REPLICATED` gives 100% data survivorability (if all nodes crashed except one - you will not loose your data).

More details you can find in documentation https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/near-caches and https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-modes